# NodeJS can not go to the folder up to execute the command from child_process.spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

To start WebPack (which is in the parent folder) I use Gulp, but as soon as I try to go to the parent folder in the path, I get an error.

Gulp

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('_Scada2', function (done) {
  spawn('webpack', [], { cwd: '../../Scada.Web/' })
    .on('close', done);
});
```

get an error

```
[14:20:47] '_Scada2' errored after 4.47 ms
[14:20:47] Error: spawn webpack ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Процесс завершен с кодом 1.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `__dirname + '../../Scada.Web/'`

Comment: not work...

https://habrastorage.org/webt/58/xv/x5/58xvx5rguxuvybxh5abpxni4f1q.png